# R data_frame error [Error: could not find function "data_frame"]

Tags: r, dataframe

I am try to create a data frame with the data_frame method.
However, I am getting a error saying "could not find function "data_frame"

`> cluster2 <- data_frame(r = rnorm(n, 5, .25), theta = runif(n, 0, 2 * pi),x =    enter code herer * cos(theta), y = r * sin(theta), cluster = 2)
Error: could not find function "data_frame"`

I searched online, I was told that data_frame is a subset of data.frame.

I tried the following and get a different error.

```
> cluster2 <- data.frame(r = rnorm(n, 5, .25), theta = runif(n, 0, 2 * pi),x = r * cos(theta), y = r * sin(theta), cluster = 2)
```

`Error in data.frame(r = rnorm(n, 5, 0.25), theta = runif(n, 0, 2 * pi),  : object 'r' not found`

Any suggestions?

Thanks ahead

Comment: Have you loaded `library(dplyr)`  For the second case, create the `data.frame` with 'r' and 'theta` and then use `transform` or `within` to create the new variable that depend on the previous variables in the dataset

Answer (score 1):

You're using r and theta as arguments in a function that you're calling in the definitions of x and y.

When you're defining the columns r and theta in your dataframe, they are not yet callable objects, but rather a part of the callable object that will be your dataframe.

You need to define r and theta beforehand.

An example of the code required is:

```
r <- rnorm(n, 5, .25)
theta <- runif(n, 0, 2 * pi)

cluster2 <- data.frame(r = r, 
                       theta = theta,
                       x = r * cos(theta),
                       y = r * sin(theta), 
                       cluster = 2)

rm(r,theta)

View(cluster2)
```